# Chained numerical comparisons in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

In PyTorch we can do comparisons between elements in tensors like so:

```py
import torch

a = torch.tensor([[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]])
b = torch.tensor([[3,4], [1,2], [2,3]])

print(a.size())
# torch.Size([3, 2])
print(b.size())
# torch.Size([3, 2])

c = a[:, 0] < b[:, 0]

print(c)
# tensor([ True, False, False])
```

However, when we try to add a condition, the snippet fails:

```py
c = a[:, 0] < b[:, 1] < b[:, 0]
```

The expected output is

```py
 tensor([ False, False,  False])
```

So, for each element in a, compare its first element with the second element of the corresponding item in b, and compare that element with the first element of the same item in b.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scratch_12.py", line 9, in 
c = a[:, 0] < b[:, 1] < b[:, 0]
RuntimeError: bool value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous

Why is that, and how can we solve it?

Comment: And what is the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate your condition in two conditions by using directly the `&` operator. As to why exactly, it's due to the syntax of `torch`.

```
c = (a[:, 0] < b[:, 1]) & (b[:, 1] < b[:, 0])
```